# XPath on nested elements with text() but no whitespace

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml

I have poor XHTML I need to parse with xpath. It looks like this:

```
<div class="foo">
  i need this text
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>sometext</span>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <span>some other text</span>
  <span>sometext</span>
</div>
```

I want to select ALL content with "i need this text" in the first div. My problem is, that the div elements contain whitespaces or other stuff, so that //div[@class="foo"]/text() is returning empty strings for the second div also. I want to ignore these empty fields, how can I do that?

Comment: Does doing something like adding [normalize-space() != ""] at the end of your query help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div
   [.//text()
        [normalize-space() = 'i need this text']
   ]
    //text()[normalize-space()]
```

This selects any non-whitespace-only text node descendant of any `div` in the document, that (the `div`) has a text-node descendant whose normalized string value is the string `"i need this text"`.

The **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)** function takes a string (the string value of the context node -- if no argument is specified) and produces from it another string in which all leading and trailing whitespace characters are deleted, and any inner group of adjacent whitespace characters is replaced by a single space.

Answer (score -1):

Try this selector:

`//span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-list mr5']/..[contains(normalize-space(text()),'Applications')]`

Comment: Please add some text.

Comment: It's not correct to use a contains function in this context. This XPath will work for "Applications 1" as well as for just "Applications". This could cause incorrect behavior and bugs.